# ¿Cómo agregar a un array datos moficados a través de pipe() -> tap()?

Tags: angular, spring, date

Todo se inicio por problemas con la fecha (Date) porque Angular me mostraba la fecha de la base de datos con un dia menos. Y en busqueda de corregir eso problema, llegue a esto:

clientes.component.ts

```
ClientesActualizado: cCliente[];

this.clienteService.getClientes(page).pipe(
        tap(response => {

          /*convertimos el content a una lista de Cliente */
          (response.content as Cliente[]).forEach(cliente => {

    //ESTO PARA PROBAR QUE MUESTRAN TODOS LOS NOMBRES
            console.log(cliente.nombre);

    //MODIFICANDO la fecha, agregandole un dia mas
            const createdAtCovert = moment(cliente.createAt).add(1, 'days');
            this.date = createdAtCovert.format('YYYY-MM-DD');


    //LO AGREGA PERO POR SEPARADO, utiliza el array para un solo cliente, no los mete todos a la vez.
              this.ClientesActualizado = [({id: cliente.id, nombre:cliente.nombre, apellido: cliente.apellido,
                email:cliente.email, createAt: this.date})];

            console.log( this.ClientesActualizado)
          });

        })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cliente.component.html

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let cliente of ClientesActualizado">
          <td>{{cliente.id}}</td>
          <td>{{cliente.nombre}}</td>
          <td>{{cliente.apellido | lowercase }}</td>
          <td>{{cliente.email}}</td>
          <td>{{cliente.createAt | date:"EEEE dd, MMMM yyyy"}}</td>

          <td>
            <button type="button" name="editar" [routerLink]="['/clientes/form', cliente.id]" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" name="eliminar" (click)='delete(cliente)' class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Quise agregar a un nuevo array con los datos moficados que obtuve de tap(response => {}), modificando la fecha, para luego mostrarlo en HTML.
Por favor espero que me puedan ayudar, o tal vez hay otra forma de corregir el error de Angular de mostrar la fecha con un día menos.
Llevo muy poco tiempo que pase al manejo de Spring y Angular

Comment: Si la fecha está mal, es posible que se envíe mal desde backend: asegúrate de que la zona horaria es correcta

Comment: Si en lugar de usar tap usas map y retornas el valor que estas asignando a this.ClientesActualizando deberias poder usar el observable de la misma manera que venias haciendolo antes de tener el problema de las fechas.